# Populate map in a thread safe way and pass that map to another method from a background thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures, thread-safety, atomic

I have a below class in which **`add`** method will be called by multiple threads to populate **`channelMessageHolder`** CHM in a thread safe way.

In the same class, I have a backgrond thread which runs every 30 seconds and it calls **`send`** method by passing data from the **`channelMessageHolder`**.

```
public class Processor {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors
      .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>> channelMessageHolder =
                new AtomicReference<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>());

  private Processor() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        send();
      }
    }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  // this will be called by only single background thread
  private void send(ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> messageByChannels) {
    for(Entry<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> entry : messageByChannels.entrySet()) {
      Channel channel = entry.getKey();
      ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message> messageHolder = entry.getValue();

      while (!messageHolder.isEmpty()) {
        Message message = messageHolder.poll();
        ....
        // process this and send to database
      }      
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads
  public void add(final Channel channel, final Message message) {
    // populate channelMessageHolder in a thread safe way
  }
}
```

**Question**

As you can see `channelMessageHolder` is already present in my `Processor` class so do I need to explicitly pass data from this map every 30 seconds to send method? Or I can directly use it in my send method?

Confusion is, if I directly use it in my send method, then it will be populated by multiple threads at the same time so that's why I am using `getAndSet` method of AtomicReference to pass it to `send` method.

Let me know if what I am doing is wrong and there is any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see channelMessageHolder is already present in my Processor class so do I need to explicitly pass data from this map every 30 seconds to send method? Or I can directly use it in my send method?

You can certainly use it directly in the `send()` method and you don't need the `AtomicReference` wrapper since `ConcurrentHashMap` is already synchronized.  What you need to worry about is that your key and value objects in the map are being properly synchronized.   I assume the `Channel` is immutable and the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is concurrent so you should be good.

```
// no need for AtomicReference
private final ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>> channelMessageHolder =
     new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>();
```

The `ConcurrentHashMap` takes care of the synchronization for you so the producer threads can add items into it at the same time that your sender thread is sending items out without clashing.  An `AtomicReference` is only needed if you were trying to share an unsynchronized class between multiple threads.

> Confusion is, if I directly use it in my send method, then it will be populated by multiple threads at the same time so that's why I am using getAndSet method of AtomicReference to pass it to send method.

Right but this ok.  Multiple threads will be adding messagesto the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.  Every 30 seconds your background thread starts up, gets the `Channel`, dequeues and then sends the messages that are in the queue at that moment.  The `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` protects against race conditions of the producer and consumer.

The problem that you have in your code is that this isn't reentrant since it relies on multiple calls to the queue:

```
while (!messageHolder.isEmpty()) {
    Message message = messageHolder.poll();
```

It works in your case because there looks to be only one thread dequeue-ing but the following code is better:

```
while (true) {
    // only one call to the concurrent queue
    Message message = messageHolder.poll();
    if (message == null) {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why we don't need atomic reference? I thought if we need all threads to see same data in the same CHM, we need that? Also I have updated  my question (in the update section) with the full code I am using. I just wanted to make sure I am getting right feedback so thought to check with the full code that I will be using. I am executing multiple channels in parallel and I will have max 5-6 channels. And Channel is an enum class in my code.

Comment: Also if we use `while true`, then it will keep running forever and in that case, then we don't need a background thread which runs every 30 seconds? Because in my case, I doubt CHM will be empty at any point of time, it will always be full so that is why I was running every 30 second but with infinite loop, it will keep running forever and next background thread won't get kicked in I assume.

Comment: `AtomicReference` would be necessary @user1950349 if you were trying to share an unsynchronized object.  Since CHM is already synchronized internally, multiple threads can share it without you having to worry about synchronizing the data yourself.  If you had used a standard `HashMap` then you would have to have used the `AtomicReference`.

Comment: Well if it is never empty then at some point the producers will fill memory right @user1950349?  Also, if `while (!messageHolder.isEmpty()) {` is always true then hen your code would also loop forever as well right?  I'm just changing the test to be more reentrant since it one makes one operation.

Comment: I see.. Yeah you are right.. Also do you see any issue in the updated  code where I am executing multiple channels in parallel. I think I did it right but wanted  to make sure? Also in the same code I am using two executors, one to start background thread and other to execute multiple channels in parallel. Does it have to be like this and it's the right way or I can use single executor here?

Comment: Please don't update your code because it invalidates the answers for posterity.  Feel free to ask another question with new code @user1950349.

Comment: sure  got it. I have removed it.. Will keep a note of that next time. Thanks for keeping me in check. I have already asked question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054655/multiple-producer-and-single-consumer-in-a-multithread-environment).

Answer (score 1):

> Or I can directly use it in my send method without passing anything

You should be able to directly use it in the `send` method by saying `channelMessageHolder.getAndSet(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Message>>())` at the beginning of the `send` method without any issues.

That said, *Java 8* has added a new method called `computeIfAbsent` to the `ConcurrentHashMap` class which means that you don't really need that `AtomicReference` that you are using.

Comment: I am still on Java 7 so I cannot use `computeIfAbsent`. Also what is the race condition and how can I fix it? And my send method will be called by a single background thread only..

Comment: Am I suppose to use any other datastructure here instead of CLQ? I started using it because of its thread safety

Comment: @user1950349 My bad. I misread `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` as `newScheduledThreadPool`. There won't be a race condition at the point where I said it would be in such a case. Thread safety is a complex topic and it would be difficult to advice further without understanding what is it that you are trying to achieve. That said, you could use one of the `BlockingQueue` implementations instead.

Comment: Sure got it. I also have updated question. Can you check and let me know if that's what you meant in the send method?

Comment: @user1950349 Yes. That change should work the same way as before.